# Adapting maximum file path length (>260 chars) for an IIS application on Windows 10 server

Tags: .net, iis

I set the registry key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled to 1, so that long paths are enabled on my system. 
Additionally every application, that should be allowed to use long file paths, needs to include a longPathAware tag in its application manifest. 
So is there a way to make this work for an IIS application? I already tried to include the longPathAware tag in an application manifest of my main .dll, but this still does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue, i.e. IIS application is failing for long path (file in request's post body). I tried @Jokies Ding's solution. Didn't work.

Comment: @Shiva yes so we ended up using the "\\?\" prefix, which worked well but maybe is not the prettiest solution.

Comment: Same here -- I couldn't get long paths to work in several ASP.NET / WCF apps running under IIS. Had to use the magic prefix "\\?\".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to modify the value of system.web/httpRuntime/maxURLLength?

The default limit of maxURLLength is 260.

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me. My use case is posting a file in body of request, that goes to a temp folder that is deeply nested and the path is over 260 chars long.